# Install driver on Windows 10 that is only compatible with Windows 7? New installer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, installation

I have drivers that supports Windows 7. It comes with an installer.

If you run that installer on Windows 10, it gives error saying it's not compatible.
If you run in compatibility mode to Windows 7 and install, it installs.

I want to install in Windows 10 without changing compatibility settings. Is there a way to create an installer or maybe a bat program to change compatibility settings and make a hassle free installation on Windows 10?

Comment: Really is it that big of a hassle?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to install it without having to manually change compatibility settings? Are you going to distribute it? If so, that is probably infringing on someone's copyright.

You can write some software that creates a registry key to ensure the program will be run in compatibility mode or you can run 2 DOS commands, one to create the registry value and another to actually run it. https://qtechbabble.wordpress.com/2016/08/23/run-application-in-compatibility-mode-from-command-line/

---

---

---

I learned that these compatibility entries are written in a straightforward fashion to the Windows Registry.  It is actually the same location used to store application-level display and privilege level settings too (more on that in a moment).  The registry key differs depending on if the setting applies to an individual user or to all users.

For an individual user: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers

For all users: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers

Note that if settings are written to the HKLM (all users) location, users cannot change the affected settings in the file properties GUI unless they are an administrator.

For each item that has custom compatibility settings, a string is made.  The name of the string is the path to the file and the data is specific to the desired compatibility setting(s):

[image: Screenshot of Registry Editor showing the keys]

There are three types of settings that can be applied to each application: compatibility mode, display settings, and privilege level.  Modify the registry value to run the file as desired.  If multiple settings are to be used, separate the data with a single space (like in the pskill.exe example pictured above: 256COLOR WIN95).

The following tables show the data values that I found:

**Compatibility Modes:**

| Description | Value Data |
| --- | --- |
| Windows 8 | WIN8RTM |
| Windows 7 | WIN7RTM |
| Windows Vista SP2 | VISTASP2 |
| Windows Vista SP1 | VISTASP1 |
| Windows Vista | VISTARTM |
| Windows XP SP3 | WINXPSP3 |
| Windows XP SP2 | WINXPSP2 |
| Windows 98 | WIN98 |
| Windows 95 | WIN95 |

**Display Settings:**

| Description | Value Data |
| --- | --- |
| 8-bit (256) Color Mode | 256COLOR |
| 16-bit (65536) Color Mode | 16BITCOLOR |
| 640 x 480 Screen Resolution | 640X480 |
| Disable Display Scaling on High DPI Settings | HIGHDPIAWARE |

**Privilege Level:**

| Description | Value Data |
| --- | --- |
| Run Program as Administrator | RUNASADMIN |

Therefore, it is possible to run a file in compatibility mode from command line…

…but it requires two commands be ran: one to create the appropriate registry value and another to run the file after the registry value has been made.

After learning this it was easy to create the following command that calls REG.EXE to create the registry value which forces my WorkstationInstaller.EXE file to run in Windows 7 compatibility mode:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /V %cd%\WorkstationInstaller.exe /T REG_SZ /D WIN7RTM /F
```

I added this single command to my batch script right before I run WorkstationInstaller.EXE.  Because this was for an SCCM application, I utilize the current directory environment variable %cd% to ensure it will always add the file location properly regardless of where the EXE exists in the CCM cache.

Comment: why this comment runs without ending?

Comment: @SafarMansoor https://qtechbabble.wordpress.com/2016/08/23/run-application-in-compatibility-mode-from-command-line/